# Replace values in pandas DatafFame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following values in pandas columns: id, score

```
   0, [{'val': 'ABC', 'xyz': 12.094842910767}]
   1, [{'val': 'ABC', 'xyz': 2.3494842910767}]
   2, [{'val': 'CDE', 'xyz': 5.422094842910767}]
   3, [{'val': 'CDE', 'xyz': 0.22094842910767}]
   4, [{'val': 'ABC', 'xyz': 0.2094842910767}]
```

I want to replace the values in "score" column

I want to replace:

- "**[{'value': 'ABC'***" with '**ABC**'
- **[{'value': 'CDE'***" with '**CDE**'

I have tried different methods but not getting desired results
for single value

```
pd['score'] = pd['score'].to_replace=r"^[{'val': 'AB.$", value='ABC', regex=True
```

Tried
for both

```
 pd['score'] = pd['score'].map({"^[{'val': 'AB.$": 'ABC', "^[{'val': 'CD.$": 'CDE'})
```

even

```
pd.replace({"score": r"^[{'val': 'AB.$"}, {"score": "ABC"}, regex=True)
```

Comment: Change your original dataframe to the versio you're looking to change. right now, values are 'ABC' ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `regex` could be the best way to get there, but if what you posted is fully representative of your whole dataset, you could use `str.split()` and some manipulations to get there:

```
df['score_refined'] = df['score'].str.split(' ',1).str[1].str[:5]
```

Will get you:

```
df

   id                                       score score_refined
0   0    {'val': 'ABC',  'xyz': 12.094842910767}]         'ABC'
1   1    {'val': 'ABC',  'xyz': 2.3494842910767}]         'ABC'
2   2  {'val': 'CDE',  'xyz': 5.422094842910767}]         'CDE'
3   3   {'val': 'CDE',  'xyz': 0.22094842910767}]         'CDE'
4   4    {'val': 'ABC',  'xyz': 0.2094842910767}]         'ABC'
```